# Is Bootstrap's grid system to be used only at page level

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I understand how to apply the classes to create rows and columns. 
You can split the page into grids. OK.

Is that the level at which the grid was created to be used ?

What about a smaller section in the corner of the page. if I want to split that small box into grids, is it appropriate to use the grid system ?

I ask cause I have seen my peers do this, however the official docs say

1. place rows in containers
2. place columns in rows
3. container widths are 1170px or 970px or etc etc depending upon device.

Well ofcourse my smaller section doesn't have this kind of width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right [you should use a container](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid), and in this case you can use the `container-fluid` which doesn't have a specific width, so it will fill it's parent. Use it inside your "smaller section in the corner of the page".

Example: http://codeply.com/go/rc4QcPvgnj

This will also ensure whatever rows/cols you use have the proper padding and alignment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Bootstrap grid at any nested level. If you're inside a column, then the widths are all relative to that column.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="col-md-4">
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
   </div>
</div>
```

Would first create a column of 50% width, and then create 3 columns of 33% width inside that 50%.

Comment: Wouldn't I have to create a row within that column before splitting it into three more columns ?

Comment: You don't have to, but IIRC rows have a negative margin to force the nested column to line up with the parent column.

Answer (score 0):

The column classes can be used anywhere on your page. They float left so you don't need to add any kind of row to hold them all together. Even if they aren't in a Bootstrap container, they'll do portions of the whole page. The classes split whatever container the elements are in into 12 parts, and they're relative to the size of the parent, no matter what it is.